# What is the Islamic approach to theory of evolution?

Tags: evolution

Peace be upon you, readers,
How does Islam refute the large amount of fossil evidence etc, I understand the answer would be hard for such a vast topic but I will appreciate all inputs, and please dont provide answers such as it is only a theory!

Comment: Questions about the status of evolution in science are a better fit for [biology.se]. Whether Islam is compatible with evolution was addressed [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/54/is-evolution-compatible-with-islam); to my knowledge, the answers saying that human evolution is acceptable in Islam represent a modernist streak that ignores what scholars say - the scholars seem to be in agreement that Adam and Hawa existed and were created without having parents, which contradicts human evolution. They don't attempt to reconcile, they say "God says this, so reject what science says".

Answer (score 0):

Salam Brother :)

I'll brief you a bit on this.
In Islam, we beleive that Adam AS was made in Jannah as a new creation.
(of course later on, he was brought to Dunya,where we live today)
But anyway, when you say the theory of evolution, you are referring to Darwinism,  which believes that all creatures, including humans evolved from previous animals (that humans came from monkeys). In Islam, we don't believe in this theory.
Of course, we believe in certain things about evolution (e.g. that dog breeds have come from (one or a few) common dog ancestor(s)), and they cross-bred, and were mutated by humans(it's history).We believe in ("speciation" , adaptation etc.) We  believe that humans have evolved in their understanding and knowledge in science, but we should remember that our ancestors were also humans, just like how Adam As was a well-mannered human, that glorified Allah. We did not come from monkeys :)

Allah has created us as a special new creation. Humans and Jinn can only go to jannah or hellfire. Because we are the only ones that have free will. All animals (monkeys, whales,etc.) they all are muslims, because the (submit to the will of Allah, in their specific way). For this reason, humans and monkeys are distinctly different :)

يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ اتَّقُواْ رَبَّكُمُ الَّذِي خَلَقَكُم مِّن نَّفْسٍ وَاحِدَةٍ وَخَلَقَ مِنْهَا زَوْجَهَا وَبَثَّ مِنْهُمَا رِجَالاً كَثِيراً وَنِسَاء (النساء ، 4: 1).

O humans! Be pious (careful of your duty) to your Lord, Who created you from a single self (soul), and from it He created its mate, and from them He has spread a multitude of men and women (Al-Nissa, 4: 1).

الَّذِي أَحْسَنَ كُلَّ شَيْءٍ خَلَقَهُ وَبَدَأَ خَلْقَ الإنْسَانِ مِنْ طِينٍ (ألسجدة ، 32: 7).

32.7. (Allah is He) who has made everything He created better, and He began the creation of the human (being) out of clay.

Evolutionist vs, Muslim debates:
(I can't post too many links ) so google this :

Video 1:

Muslim and Atheist discuss the theory of evolution

Video2:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC9Zgd1yW1U

Video 3:

Can we as Muslims in Islam believe in theory of evolution?

Darwinism theory:
https://i0.wp.com/www.rtgmin.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/evolution-tree.jpg